# Can I use one integer with different value? Each value has a key

Tags: ios

Can I use one integer with different value? Each value has a key.

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _level = 0 forKey: @"_level0"]; 
[[NSUserDefaults   standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger: _level = 1 forKey: @"_level1"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Table

```
NSString *level0 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"_level0"];
int level00 =[level0 intValue];
NSString *level1 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"_level1"];
int level11 =[level1 intValue];




    if (indexPath.row == 0 && level00 == 0) {
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
      else if (indexPath.row == 1 && level11 == 1) {
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }
```

If I fulfill the condition `if (indexPath.row == 1 && level11 == 1)` Image shown in first and second table cell. But image should show only in the second cell.

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you explain little bit ? What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: add to question. Clear?

Comment: You are saving with a key `_level0` and retrieving with `level0`. Looks like a typo there.

Comment: it's a typo. add to question

Comment: why don't you just save it as an array?

Comment: How can i do this? Could write it in code, please?